# Qutip - Use of Create vs Fock state functions

Tags: quantum-state, qutip

I'd like to understand the physical difference between the states created using the following two means, i.e. state1 and state2:

```
    from qutip import *
    modes  = 4
    vaccum = fock(modes)
    c_op   =  create(modes)

    
    state1 = fock(modes, 2)
    state2 = c_op*c_op*vaccum
```

The output obtained shows:

```
> state1 
> [[0]
   [0]
   [1]
   [0]]
```

and

```
> state2
> [[0]
   [0]
   [1.41421356]
   [0]]
```

The first one is described as a fock state with two particles, and the second one as a fock state two excitations. While I understand the latter, the former is not clear to me - help would be really appreciated!